What's the minimum number of points worth clustering?
I'm using HDBSCAN to cluster vector embeddings of sentences. The embeddings are being drawn from an online SQL table that's constantly being updated. At peak times, this means 1,000 embeddings an hour, but at a minimum it means 10.
I would like to cluster every hour, but I'm concerned that 10 embeddings would produce a meaningless, potentially erroneous set of clusters. This concerns me because I'd like to track the cluster's centroids and how they shift over time.
Is there a lower limit on the number of points you need to have a meaningful cluster?

There's no correct answer.  You would be in a better position than any of us to judge.

Could you clarify why I'm in a better position to judge?

You know the number of clusters, the criteria that distinguish them, the effectiveness of each criterion, and the typical level of separation between and among clusters.

Well, no, I don't. Have I said something that makes you assume I do know? Are you saying I could derive it quantitatively from the embeddings?

If you don't know any of those things, then your question isn't answerable.

There isn't a strict minimum, but our clustering algorithm may indeed impose us some restrictions. Assuming we are using HDBSCAN/DBSCAN: the number of minimum points (minPts) to form a dense region is a crucial hyperparameter. As such, if we have fewer points to cluster than our minPts value, the clustering is not really meaningful.
Another point to make is that there is a reference to "embeddings of sentences" in the question. Sentence embeddings are rarely low-dimensional (e.g. the BERT-base sentence embeddings typically have a dimensionality of 768), which further increases our size demands.
HDBSCAN/DBSCAN ultimately rely on finding fixed-radius nearest neighbours for each point: as the dimensionality of the data increases, this nearest neighbour (NN) finding task becomes more and more attenuated. That is because high-dimensional density estimation is a typical scenario where the curse of dimensionality manifest; therefore, we should realistically be using 2–3 dimensions at most. (potentially via UMAP, t-SNE, etc.) While there are no hard and fast rules of thumbs about it, density estimation with less than 30–50 points even in 2D case is generally considered very fishy and the same will extend for HDBSCAN/DBSCAN results.
(And also, as an aside, if we know our data are noisy, a very small sample can be unreliable to generate a density estimate.)
The above being said, a clustering is rarely useful on its own. As suggested by ronaldo2, business logic/subject mater knowledge is crucial to determine the utility of a clustering.

Interestingly, the clusters I made work quite well despite the curse of dimensionality! Why do you think that is? Dimensionality is 384 at the moment, thinking of going higher for more semantic meaning.

Good! :) I don't have access to your data to comment fully, but if we have thousands of points, probably we are fine. The other obvious thing why this would work is that there might be a very strong underlying structure anyway, so "most algorithms" would do well.
Something I didn't comment in my answer: I don't know what distance metric is used, but for example, cosine similarity is often preferable when clustering embeddings as it measures the angle between the two vectors, i.e. is primarily concerned with the direction of them, ignoring their magnitude.

(Magnitude is more affect by length, sentence structure, etc. Angle will look more into semantic similarity.)

Excellent, Cosine similarity is the metric I'm using! If I went to D=4000, do you think I would struggle?

Depends on your N really... But I would consider some dimension reduction technique at some point, we can't add features endlessly.

Okay, only issue is it would have to be a dimensionality reduction across all semantic embeddings. I guess that would be fine, but I would be worried that any initial sample I chose to come up with the reduction, no matter how large and representative at the time, would slowly drift into being unrepresentative, decreasing accuracy.

Just fit your dimensionality reduction on a large sample and then reuse it. We don't want to rerun PCA/UMAP in each little subsample. It will be expensive and likely to overfit.
